# What values of components to use in this 30V-2V, 3A(max) current limiting circuit?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, bjt, current-limiting

[image: [1]: https://imgur.com/cHpGO7l "schematic"]

I'm looking for a current limiting circuit for my lab bench PSU, and found this one.

What are the values for the components? Is R_sense the pot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information here for us to help. What current range do you want? What voltage?

Comment: Sorry, I've posted them in the title, it's 30V-2V DC and 3A.

Comment: @thegamebusterpl Are you expecting the output voltage to be regulated by your power supply, while at the same time you have some kind of current limit *knob* that lets you set a current limit that will "kick in" at appropriate times? Or are you looking ONLY for a way to turn your lab bench supply into a current source at times? Different things.

Comment: Jonk - I'm looking to have a way to limit my current in a range of 0.something to 2A, after regulating and stepping down voltage with a _knob_. This will function at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it works:

- R1 biases on Q1 and the collector current starts to increase.
- When the voltage across R<sub>sense</sub> rises to about 0.6 V Q2 begins to turn on and steal the bias from Q1.
- The output stabilises with 0.6 V across R<sub>sense</sub>.

For 3 A max current limiting \$ R_{sense} = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {0.6}{3} = 0.2 \ \Omega \$.

> Is R sense the pot?

No. This is a fixed-current constant current source. Pots don't come in low values like that. 100 Ω would be a low value in most potentiometer series.

Comment: You could do something with a fixed resistor in parallel with a potentiometer to trim the current, if you wanted to.

Comment: Give an example of the fixed R and variable R and let's do some current calculations.

Comment: so 1k for pot and 10ohm fixed?

Comment: So what happens when you want 3 A? You have to wind the pot down to 0.2 Ω (that's 0.02% of the track resistance) and you've got 3 A running through a 1/4 W pot with a max track current of \$ I = \sqrt {\frac {P}{R}} = \sqrt {\frac {0.25}{1000} } = 16 \ \mathrm {mA} \$. As well as being possible to adjust the pot won't last a second.

Comment: Oh,sorry by 3A i meant the max current possible, normal operation would probobly only 1A.

Comment: You've got to design for worst case. 1 A is still way to much. This circuit is not suitable for your application.

Comment: @Transistor To be excessively pedantic, [2 ohm trimmers](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-foil-resistors-division-of-vishay-precision-group/Y50502R00000K0L/Y50502R00000K0L-ND/6028641) do exist, though they're not exactly practical with an 18-week lead time and a minimum purchase quantity of 1000... That said, some [25-turn 10-ohm trimmers](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bourns-inc/3296W-1-100LF/3296W-100LF-ND/1088042) could do the job as well. So you technically could make this work, it's just not the best option.

Comment: So, what circut would you reccomend? I know that you can use the lm317 to limit the current, but you either have to use a large value pot (expensive) or a JFET (rare and expensive). I heard about some diode to replace the JFET as a cont. curr. source.

Comment: I think you are taking the wrong approach. Your bench power supply, apparently, is an adjustable voltage type but does not have adjustable current limit. Adding an external current limit will affect the voltage stability of the output so you will have lost regulation. You need to either buy a better bench PSU or design a PSU with adjustable voltage and current and feed this with your existing PSU. Forget the LM317. With 30 V in and a couple of volts out it will dissipate close to 900 W at 3 A. (It can't.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice. I'm going to replace the lm317 with the lm350 for better amprage. Also I'm going to do current reg. with a high power resistor. Thanks for all your help!